# Jquery - selecting items within forms and posting them

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a simple html page below calling a global.js file the global.js file calls a php file that gets a location for a name if it is in a database. (could have put it all on the one page but was following a tutorial).

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html
   <head>
<title>AJAX Database</title>
</head>
<body>

Name: <input type = "text" id="name">
<br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Get Loc">


<div id="output"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
</body>
 </html>
```

global.js is :

```
$('#submit').on('click',function() {
var name = $('#name').val();
if($.trim(name) != ''){
   $.post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
    $('div#output').text(data);
      });
}
});
```

it works fine as is, but if I put in  tags as shown below, it won't work. I also want to use a fieldset, but I can't even get it to work with form tags.

I have used other selectors but it won't work.
The problem seems to be the submit button, as it works if that is out of the form..
any ideas? I think using the submit within the form is getting the $.post function to send more than I want it too.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html
 <head>
<title>AJAX Database</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
Name: <input type = "text" id="name">
<br />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Get Loc">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
</body>
 </html>
```

the php file is:

```
 if(isset($_POST['name']) === true && empty($_POST['name']) === false) {
  require '../db/connect.php';

$query = mysql_query("
SELECT `names`.`location`
FROM    `names`
WHERE `names`.`name` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name'])) . "'

");
echo (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? mysql_result($query,0,'location') : 'Name not found';

 }
```

Is my problem not using the right selectors, or is there some rule about using selectors for submit buttons within forms ?

Comment: preventDefault() action of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of the form. Either by using `event.preventDefault()` or adding `return false` at the end of the function.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    if ($.trim(name) != '') {
        $.post('ajax/name.php', {
            name: name
        }, function(data) {
            $('div#output').text(data);
        });
    }
});​
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. I used the e.preventDefault(); as you suggested and it worked fine with the form and fieldset tages etc. Do you think JQuery is worth getting good at? Since in cases like this plain javaScript with a form and a post method, would work just as well. Sometimes I think although Jquery is a shorthand form of JavaScript, the learning involved and sometimes work-arounds needed are not worth the effort of just having shorter code? What do you think? Any recommendations on how to learn it well ?

Comment: I personally recommend it. There's a lot of potential for easy code writing and reuse. Simply having the selectors alone makes it worth it for me. I'd much rather type $('#idName') than document.getElementById('idName'); - and even more so for classes and element names, you dont have to worry about crossbrowser quirks. Another good reason is that a lot of major companies use jQuery - so knowing it well will help in your job searching :)

Comment: Plain JS would have had the same issue. Also in both cases, please assign onsubmit of the form rather than onclick of the submit!

Comment: @mplungjan Good catch, updated the answer. OP, you may want to assign an ID to the form and grab it instead of just $('form') in case there are multiple forms on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise not to use the click of the button but instead I suggest this

```
<!doctype html>
 <html
 <head>
   <title>AJAX Database</title>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
   <script src="js/global.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="form1">
    Name: <input type="text" id="name"><br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Get Loc">
  </form>

  <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where the script is

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    if ($.trim(name) != '') {
        $.post('ajax/name.php', {
            name: name
        }, function(data) {
            $('div#output').text(data);
        });
    }
    else {
      alert('Please enter name');
      $('#name').focus();
    }
});​
```